# Android deep linking web url format error

Tags: android, web, deep-linking

I have integrated deeplinking to my article app and added this code to my artical detail web page.

```
<link rel="alternate"
          href="android-app://com.example.android/myapp" />
```

When I search an article on google and click an article it goes to my app

```
String action = intent.getAction();
String data = intent.getDataString();
```

but here is the data variable comes as normal link(www.myapp.com/...), not like formatted(android-app://....)

Why does it come like a usual link but not formatted according to deep linking format?

I  have intent-filters on my manifest file :

```
<activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">


     <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="http"
                        android:host="www.myapp.com"
                        android:pathPrefix="" />
     </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
                  <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="myapp"
                      android:pathPrefix="" />
              </intent-filter>

     </activity>
```

Comment: ... because the link you're sending is `android-app://com.example.android/myapp` and not `www.myapp.com` ? Or wait, better question - can you show us your `IntentFilter` from AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @Shark I added intents to my manifest file <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.myapp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="" />
 </intent-filter>

Comment: Try adding the `pathPattern` and try again, this looks ok on the first look.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to your intent filter defined in the AndroidManifest for your activity, please share the piece that looks like this:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySplash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebpage.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebpage.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="127.0.0.1" android:pathPattern=".*" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="127.0.0.1" android:pathPattern=".*" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.webpage.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.webpage.com" android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then I get my stuff from the clicked link like this:

```
        // check if this intent is started via custom scheme link
    if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("DEEPLINK", "Deep link data detected, initializing in deep link mode...");
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String origin = intent.getDataString();
        //Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(origin));
        String actionString = uri.getQueryParameter("action"); // get 'action'

        //fetch possible NUM variations: nmbr, num, arg
        String pno_alias1 = uri.getQueryParameter("nmbr"); // get 'pno'
        String pno_alias2 = uri.getQueryParameter("num"); // get 'pno'
        String pno_alias3 = uri.getQueryParameter("arg"); // get 'pno'

        String pno = (pno_alias1 == null) ? ( (pno_alias2 == null) ? (pno_alias3 == null ? null : pno_alias3) : pno_alias2 ) : pno_alias1;

        importantNumber = pno;
        //fetch possible zip variations: plz, zip
        String zip_alias1 = uri.getQueryParameter("zip"); // get 'zip'
        String zip_alias2 = uri.getQueryParameter("plz"); // get 'plz'
        String zip = (zip_alias1 == null) ? ( (zip_alias2 == null) ? null : zip_alias2 ) : zip_alias1;

        Toast.makeText(this, "Intent URI: " + uri + "\n\nAction: " + actionString + "\nPNO: " + pno + "\nZip: " + zip, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Parameter names: " + uri.getQueryParameterNames() + "\n\nOrigin string: " + origin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (actionString != null && !actionString.isEmpty())
            deepLinkActionType = DeepLinkActionType.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(actionString));

        Log.d("DEEPLINK", "deep link action type: " + deepLinkActionType + "\tPNO: " + pno + "\tZIP: " + zip);
```

My deeplink URIs look like this:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=1&nmbr=09981122341088&zip=11000`

`http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=1&num=09981122341088`

`http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=3`

Feel free to take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Comment: Still data is like "www.myapp.com/..." not formatted. Do you receive a formatted link when you click a link from Google web mobile app search results? Is it related to my web side codes? Do you only add link href to your web site codes?

Comment: @Turquoise ok, i hope this helps you. Using the `pathPattern` will return only the query behind the `/` char, and you'll need to parse it and rip out the arguments you need (or might find there). In my example I have up to 3-4 copies of one due to the lousy backend that sends them differently every now and then.

Comment: When you type under head tag of your web page <link href="android-app://com.example.android/mywebsite/action=3" do you receive a link like "http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=3" from intent to your app?

Comment: yes, i get the full link like that. I get the same 3 URIs I pasted.

Comment: But if we set our link href as "android-app://com.example.android/mywebsite/action=3" why do we receive a url like "http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=3" ? I mean I think i could receive a formatted url like "android-app://com.example.android/mywebsite/action=3". Right?

Comment: Yes, using the approach I posted above, here's the results (logcat) I get for `origin`:
`ORIGIN: http://www.mywebsite.com/?action=1&num=09981122341088&zip=63741`
 and commented-out `uri2`: `URI: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F%3Faction%3D1%26num%3D09981122341088%26zip%3D63741` (now you understand why it's commented out, it's useless).
So yes, the answer is **yes**. You get the full URI that was clicked.